# powershell script to get the status of failed jobs which are running in the application reading the json file from a odata query uri

Tags: json, powershell, odata

I need to have filtered data from a odata query formatted in json file, i wanted to use the powershell script to read out that json file and get the results of the failed status jobs

below is the example uri:

```
https://app.name.com//odata/ScheduledJobs?$format=json&$expand=Application($select=Id,Name,AssetId;$expand=Asset($select=Id,Name)),JobType,JobInstances($filter=StartTime+eq+null;$orderby=NextRunTime+asc;$top=1),CompletedJobs($orderby=StartTime+desc;$top=1;$expand=State;$select=Id,StateId,StartTime,EndTime)&$top=20&$orderby=ScheduleStart&$filter=Enabled+eq+true&$count=true
```

when I tried to use the powershell script as below to convert it to csv i get the following message, i do not know how to proceed further, please help me, i am a beginner at powershell scripting.

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\ScheduledJobs1.json'
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select-Object -expand results | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Set-Content 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\sai.csv'
```

please tell me how can I get results of the failed status jobs in the application and get that information in a tabular format...

Comment: I don't see the message you mention. [Edit] your question to contain it and view the changes made to your question to enhance formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not in a position to test this right now. But try using `Export-csv` instead of `set-content`.

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\ScheduledJobs1.json'
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select-Object -expand results |
    Export-csv 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\sai.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```